# How to parse the xml to Doc using DomParser in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a document which is 10MB in file size. Actually, It was parsing previously. Now, I am getting null object for the document.  don't get the error where i was doing wrong. Please find me the solution.

```
class Parser {
    Document doc;

    Parser() {
        doc = null;
    }

    public void readXmlToDom(String path, String uuid) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            doc =
                documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
        }
        catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationExceptione) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except i am ending with null object..Please solve this problem anyone.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: How do you know it's a null object?

Comment: Do you see any exceptions? Is your `path` proper?

Comment: And depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you should eventually consider using a SAXParser instead of a DOMParser since its quite memory-consuming (looking at your 10MB file)..
And doc will be null by default - no need for init in the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `serialize` the Document if you want to output it like this.

You could do it that way:

```
public static byte[] serializeDOM(Document doc) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;
    try {
      Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
      os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
      transformer.transform(source, result);
      return os.toByteArray();
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
    }
  }
```

Doing it the way you do it will always output "null" (which doesn't mean that the object is `null`).

Also you should wrap your `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` and close it properly once you're done.